# Быстродействие версий .net framework

Tags: .net, производительность

Есть ли разница в скорости выполнения одного и того же кода на разных версиях фреймворка (при выставлении соответствующей версии в свойствах проекта и перекомпиляции)? В частности интересует 4, 4.5, 4.6

Comment: Как и во всех вопросах о производительности, результат зависит от самого кода, настроек, объёма памяти, загруженности системы, направления ветра в Редмонде, дня недели, популяции папуасов на Новой Гвинее и расстояния до Альфа Центавра. Измерьте сами.

Comment: Т.е. с большой вероятностью можно получить результаты на которые влияют только погрешности измерений, а не смена целевой версии фреймворка.

Comment: @Welt, С большой вероятностью какие бы вы данные не получили на своей машине, они могут быть не истинными. Что бы найти истину Вам нужно тестить на разных машинах, танцуя с разными бубнами и использовать не Stopwatch, а какой нибудь надежный benchmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разница есть почти всегда. Ваш вопрос слишком абстрактный. В каком-то конкретном случае определенная версия быстрее, в другом случает быстрее другая версия. Однозначно сказать что какая-то версия фреймворка быстрее всегда, думаю, не будет правильно.

Comment: Спасибо, т.е. разница для неизменного кода может быть. Тогда стоит потратить время на тестирование. Просто считал что версии отличаются функционалом/безопасностью.

Comment: @Welt: А так же другим jitter'ом.

Comment: @Welt, однозначно стоит тратить время на тестирование, если это Вам только нужно или Вы пишете Critical performance code. Так же вы можете использовать разный JIT-компилятор (как подсказал `VlaD`) с разными фреймворками. Так что тут много вариантов решения задачи, которая решается эмпирическим путем.